# Unable to create database in InfluxDB using API call from Postman

Tags: rest, postman, influxdb

I am trying to create a Database in InfluxDB using API call from Postman. I have setup the configuration as mentioned in the InfluxDB [Documentaion](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/api-guide/postman/).

When I tried to do a POST call to create a DB, I end up with the below error:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id": 0,
            "error": "not implemented: CREATE DATABASE"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Postman API Call]

Comment: Are you on InfluxDB <2.0.0? Not sure if the /query endpoint still works with v2.0.0+